# How to dynamically change a field depending on a unique date formula

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, visualforce, soql

I'm working on a work schedule of sorts, a feature that I'm trying to create would be one that can be setup initial and would not need to be touched ever again. However I'm not sure where to even start; I have a weekly schedule with three different fields, a middle field that is unique and requires no attention and a day/night field. My user is able to drag users into these fields and set that they are expected to working during that period. However as my user has different shifts that sometimes overlap I'm looking to color code each of the shifts of which there is a total of five, the shifts go on a pattern of working: 2 nights, than 2 days off, than 3 days working and lastly than 2 days off. What would be the best approach of mapping this as I cannot simply put that Monday nights are color X as the by the time next weeks comes around the shift would be starting on Wednesday, along side this some shifts will be working at the same time so the color coding should not cover the entire day but only a limited number of entries (2). My initial idea was to try using Hashmap or something of the sort but I'm uncertain how I would structure it to achieve what I'm looking for..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop experience would be nice but I assume not mandatory, so can try to use standard features. Im not sure which user is using this - the worker doing the shift, or a manager allocating workers to the shifts? If is for a manager - If you created a 'shift' object and had shifts represented as records you'd be able to create list views of those shifts ie. 'next n days','this month' etc.  Then you could use bulk action within the list view to assign a user to multiple shift records at a time. Would be reasonably efficient and quick to build. Just a thought... (and I couldnt follow what you meant about color coding sorry.)